# Rails devise pundit omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, authorization, omniauth

I want to implement a multiple user role system, can I integrate devise with pundit and omniauth?

It seems that pundit just offer 2-role authorization, how can I set up 3 roles in pundit?

Like user->premium user->admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple roles on pundit by enumerating different roles in your User model.
For example, in your user.rb file(or whatever your model file is called), you can add a line

```
enum role: [:user, :premium_user, :admin]
```

and refer to these roles later on.